# Purim in Adar and not Av?

Tags: purim, tisha-bav, haman

We all presume that Haman was well literate and familiar with our Tanachic sources. It is widely known that since the sin of the Spies (Meraglim) 9th of Av was chosen for all kinds of misfortunes for Am Israel.

I don't know if they observed the 9th of Av and the destruction of the latest Temple back in Persia, but the month was known for its bad luck.

On the other hand, as I recall, there were no bad events in Adar and Moses' death was albeit a "punishment" for Moses but not for the whole people that were about to enter the Promised Land with Yehoshua.

Why Haman didn't decide straight on the 9th of Av to complete the destruction of the Jewish nation?

Comment: It could be that it wasnt so well known yet,but the Esther Rabbah does mention that the Pur did not fall on the month if av since the month said that enough calamities happened. Good question though

Comment: *We all presume* We do?

Comment: @Alex A good point. Similarly to Pharaoh, we expect a high level of intelligence, and unlike Pharao, the Tanach (most parts) were already written. Also you have to know your enemy to know where to hurt. What do you think - he didn't?

Comment: I think that there is certainly a school of commentary that likes to assume that the villains knew the Torah, but that might be ahistorical.

Answer (score 2):

The 9th of *Av* is destined to be overturned to a joyous day and *Haman* didn't want to risk that underlying power of the month of *Av* to kick-start the redemption, which is is why he instead elected an 'empty' month where no underlying surprises await!

Comment: If the Jews were dead H"V there would be no joyous day. Av is definitely the bad luck for the Jews, I don't see the trouble. He'd prefer to hurt the Jews at their lowest.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question NS. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site, in particular MY is putting significant emphasis on sources since we don't really know you. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Thinking....

If anyone did what the meraglim did,
Then for them tisha b’av is THEIR
Demise!!!!
Haman was doing exactly what 
Meraglim did!!!
A) Loshon hora on EY
B)cause the Jews  to be scared by 
    Spreading rumors of death
C)Claims of HKB”H unable to do 
    Anything 
D)many ego issues/loss of power

So haman stayed away from tisha b’av

(Which is a bad day for Am Yisrael and 
we sit and remember again and again 
The errors of the meraglim)

since haman knew that since he is 
following  the errors of the meraglim 
He will only lose on that day like
The meraglim

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a moment to look at our [tour] for some useful information about the site, as it might work differently from one’s you’re used to. This seems to be more a comment than an answer to the question at hand; can you [edit] it to directly address why Haman didn’t pick the 9th of Av?